# Not able to mount data on DOM

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to vuejs ...I am not able to mount the data of component to the blade file

**app.js**

```
Vue.component('example-component', 
require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

**home.blade.php**

```
 <div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>
 </div>
```

**ExampleComponent.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
}
```

There was no error but 
   element example-component
 was displayed as it is ..I want to display Component mounted on console?

Comment: Have you run `npm run dev` / `npm run watch` to recompile your vue files?

Comment: yes, I hv run this commands

Answer (score 0):

I have found the thing i have missed while coding is that,

I have not included app.js file...

After including this file i overcome my output..